# Java: Randomly generated numbers only appear in small part of given range

Tags: java, random, integer

I'm working on a game and I want my enemies to spawn with a delay between 1-5 seconds. My code for that part looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void run() {

    try {
        while (true) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int cooldownTime = r.nextInt((5000 - 1000) + 1) + 1000;
            long lastSpawn = 0;
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (time > lastSpawn + cooldownTime) {
                System.out.println(cooldownTime);
                addEnemies();
                lastSpawn = time;
            }
```

If I understand nextInt correctly this should spawn enemies 1000-5000 ms apart every time, but my results are really weird and I can't quite figure out why. This is an example of what it would look like if I print `cooldownTime`.

2523

1190

1095

1061

1168

1119

1052

1159

1071

1076

1000

1394

1249

1070

And so on... It seems that the first enemy is truly spawned randomly and the others are always in the low 1000's. This happens every time. Does anyone know why it's like that? I'm quite lost.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, it generated random numbers between 1000 and 5000 fine for me.

Comment: I'm getting random numbers in the entire range. That said, you shouldn't create a new Random instance in each iteration. Use the same instance.

Comment: Remove the `addEnemies()` and see if it runs correctly, that is the only thing we can't run ourselves to see what is going wrong, since it is working for us.

Comment: Take the Random object creation and the lastSpawn variable out of the loop.

Comment: Of course, you are only printing the random number if `(time > lastSpawn + cooldownTime)`, so perhaps that condition is true only for low values of the random number.

Comment: How long does `addEnemies()` take?  Does it run in its own thread?  Also, why use a CPU hogging busy loop - why not use `sleep()` (which would simplify the loop)?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I had `long lastSpawn = 0;` outside of the while loop. If I put it in with the rest of the code (like i did in my SO-post), i get random integers aswell. The problem is that when I do that my enemies spawn super fast and not with the delay...

Comment: But that's exactly what Eran told you: if you print only when `time > lastSpawn+cooldownTime`, then you'll only have them printed when they are in the range when that happens.

Comment: Also, consider adding a Thread.sleep(...) in the loop to get your program to take actions in discrete steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Random r = new Random();` repeatedly is extremely pathological and ruins the statistical properties of the generator. (The results you get are most likely a strong function of your system clock time.)

Do that step once and your results will be far better. (There are also more efficient ways to implement a delay than this - consider `sleep` - Java compilers are not yet optimising out burn loops.)

Note also that your observations are further complicated by the fact that you are not printing every number drawn.

Comment: It works now.... Thanks! I thought I tried this out but apparently not... Just newbie things I guess... thanks again!!

Comment: @snorkish The location of the creation of the Random object was not the only issue with your code. The way you are calculating the offset from the lastSpawn variable, as well as where you declare those variables, is going to give you wrong results every time. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this your exact issue, but you had some problems with the logic of `System.currentTimeMillis()` and were just looking at the total current time and not the difference between the time.

Additionally you only want to look for a new random value once the `if` actually executes so you do not generate a `Random` number each `loop` iteration, but rather each time an enemy spawns you generate a new one for the next enemy.

Here is the modified code that takes all of this into account:

```
Random r = new Random();
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
int cooldownTime = r.nextInt((5000 - 1000) + 1) + 1000;
while (true) {
    long timeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

    if (timeDifference > cooldownTime) {
        //addEnemies();
        System.out.println(timeDifference); //Prints the time taken for enemy to spawn
        cooldownTime = r.nextInt((5000 - 1000) + 1) + 1000;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis(); //set the initial time again
    }
}
```

This will generate a random number between 1000 and 5000 and execute the `if` block each time after the delay, resetting the values in the `if` to do it forever.

However, there are most likely better ways to add a delay to your logic like some comments pointed out(`sleep`), but this is the corrected logic for your method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, several of your variables are being created INSIDE the loop. You need to move the creation of the `Random` object, as well as the `lastSpawn` and `cooldown` variables outside the loop. This is because the `lastSpawn` variable is being overwritten each time the loop executes with 0, meaning you're always checking if the current time is greater than 0. You need to store it outside the loop so that it will retain the last value you assigned to it. For the same reason, `cooldown` needs to be outside the loop because you're generating a new cooldown every loop, and `System.currentTimeMillis()` is ALWAYS going to be larger than it because `System.currentTimeMillis()` gets you the system time offset from January 1, 1970. Finally, as `System.currentTimeMillis()` is represented by a long, you'll want any time-related variables to be long as well, otherwise you could end up overflowing your variable if the current time in milliseconds is too high for an integer to store.

Here is a better way to achieve what you're looking to do:

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomCooldown {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastSpawn = start;
        long cooldown = getCooldown(rand);

        while(true) {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsed = (time - lastSpawn);
            if(elapsed >= cooldown) {
                System.out.println("Adding enemies!");
                cooldown = getCooldown(rand); // only generate a new cooldown once the old cooldown has been surpassed
                lastSpawn = time;
            }
        }
    }

    public static long getCooldown(Random rand) {
        return (long)((rand.nextInt(4000) + 1) + 1000);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion that works as I think you like. I has not one but two loops. The outer loop generates new enemies and the inner loop makes updates (not sure how much of that this enemy generating thread needs to update but included it just in case).

```
public void run() {
    Random r = new Random();
    // setup 
    while (true) {
        int wait = r.nextInt((5000 - 1000) + 1) + 1000;
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Adding enemies at " + time
                + ", next add roughly in " + wait + " ms.");
        while (wait + time > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // update  
        }
    }
}
```

The Random object is reused and the call Thread.sleep(30) makes the thread hand over control for 30 ms, a time during which the CPU can do more useful things than busy wait. (30 is BTW not a magic number that must be used but just a number I chose. You need to experiment and find what number works best in your game.)

The print out shows what happens.

```
Adding enemies at 1565096018610, next add roughly in 2890 ms.
Adding enemies at 1565096021530, next add roughly in 2301 ms.
Adding enemies at 1565096023863, next add roughly in 4944 ms.
Adding enemies at 1565096028813, next add roughly in 3042 ms.
Adding enemies at 1565096031879, next add roughly in 2661 ms.
```

... and so on. The actual numbers will not be the same of course when you run this code but similar.

Hope this helps and good luck with your game!

Answer (score -2):

It looks fine to me. You should probably use the same `Random()` instance for each iteration. And remember: humans have no ability to perceive randomness. Alternatively, you could try seeding the Random-Generator (using the `Random(long seed)` constructor), just in case there's some weird stuff happening with your seed.